# Formula for calculating total yearly payments with yearly escalation over $x $ years

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My knowledge on math/terminology is pretty terrible so seeking some help with a formula (which I'll be converting to javascript to be used in a calculator).

I'm trying to calculate the total amount paid over X years, with each year compounded up by an escalation percentage.

---

For example,

Yearly Payments = $£24,000$

Yearly Escalation = $3.5$%

Payment Length = $7.373$ years

---

I've been digging many many similar questions, but none match my scenario.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. A person pays every year $24,000$. The bank gives $3.5$% interest each year. But you want to know the total amount paid. If you pay $24,000$ each year, after $7$ years, this is $24,000\cdot 7$.

Comment: I think I may have used the wrong terminology, I was never good with this sort of stuff - to put it into context.. I'm trying to calculate the total cost of a care home over 7.373 years with a yearly escalation of 3.5%, so year 1 would be **24,000** + **840**, year 2 would be **24840** + **869.40**, year 3 would be **25,709.40** + **899.829**.. and so on. I'm looking for the total of all of those years (including decimal).

Comment: I don't understand the term escalation. If your payment is £24,000 for 7.373 years, the cost of the mortgage is £176,952. If you mean the interest is floating and increasing, we have a more complex problem: Is the 3.5% increase on the payment or the principal. If it's on the principal, we need to know the current interest rate to know the amount of principal. If it's just an increased payment, it's rediculous finance but the previous comment explains how.

Comment: Escalation = inflation. So we have a service that initially costs 24,000 (just an example number) per year, and it is compounded each year by 3.5% inflation (an example percentage) for 7.373 years. I need to find the total costs after all the compounding/inflation over the 7.373 years.

Comment: Here's another example [link](http://www.easysurf.cc/samt8n3.htm?ansal=24000&ipcsal=3.5&time=7.373)

Comment: @JMD And do you want to know the salary after $7.373$ years, or do you wanna know all the money you earned till the $7.373$th year?

Comment: I'm looking for the formula to calculate the total earned up until the 7.373rd year (or whatever year I specify in the formula).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the formula for regular deposit

$Amount = \frac{D\times[(1+r)^t-1]}{r}$

The total amount after 7.373 years if deposit 24,000 per year with the yearly interest rate = 3.5%  and compounded yearly will be

$\frac{24000\times[(1+0.035)^{7.373}-1]}{0.035}$

You may finish the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

The following derivation assumes a starting salary $x$ compounds according to certain interest rate $p$ each year, with the amount earned right after the first year being $(1+p)x$. Next, during any given year, an employee is paid $m$ times in equal payments which add up to the total salary for that year. You are asking for the total amount $A$ that the employee has earned after $N$ years, where $N$ need not be a whole number.

The strategy I used to find the formula was to calculate the amount earned after $\lfloor N \rfloor$ years, and then the amount earned during the remaining time, which is part of the $(\lfloor N \rfloor + 1)^\text{th}$ year.

The notation I use is $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ for the floor function, and $[\cdot]$ for the integer part of a number. You may be familiar with these from your programming experience.

We first calculate the amount earned after $\lfloor N \rfloor$ years. As was shown in your link, the amount earned $A$ after the first year is $$A(1) = (1+p)\cdot x.$$ After 2 years, it is $$A(2) = (1+p)\cdot x + (1+p)\cdot(1+p)\cdot x.$$ So after $\lfloor N \rfloor$ years, it is $$A(\lfloor N \rfloor) = (1+p)\cdot x + \dots + (1+p)^{\lfloor N \rfloor} \cdot x = (1+p)\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor N \rfloor}(1+p)^{k-1}x.$$ Using the [formula for the partial sum of a geometric progression](http://mathematics.laerd.com/maths/geometric-progression-intro.php), this can be simplified to $$A(\lfloor N \rfloor) = (1+p)\frac{(1+p)^{\lfloor N \rfloor}-1}{p}x. $$

Then, we calculate the amount that the employee earns during the remaining time. In your question, this is $0.373$ of the $8^{\text{th}}$ year. The amount earned from one payment in the $(\lfloor N \rfloor + 1)^{\text{th}}$ year is $$\frac{1}{m} (1+p)^{\lfloor N \rfloor + 1}x.$$

The number of times $k$ that the employee gets paid in the $(\lfloor N \rfloor + 1)^\text{th}$ year is $$k = \text{floor}\left(\frac{N - \left[N\right]}{\frac{1}{m}}\right) = \lfloor m(N -[N]) \rfloor.$$ So, the amount earned in the $(\lfloor N \rfloor + 1)^\text{th}$ year is $$\left(\frac{1}{m}\left(1+p\right)^{\lfloor N \rfloor + 1}x \right)k.$$ The total amount earned after $N$ years is then $$A(N) = A(\lfloor N \rfloor) + \frac{1}{m}\left(1+p\right)^{\lfloor N \rfloor + 1}kx,$$ which ends up as $$A(N) = (1+p)\frac{(1+p)^{\lfloor N \rfloor}-1}{p} x+ \frac{1}{m}\left(1+p\right)^{\lfloor N\rfloor + 1}x\lfloor m(N -[N]) \rfloor.$$

For example, in your question, you specify $x = 24000$, $p = 0.035$, $N = 7.343$. Lets say employees get payed bi-weekly, so they get payed $26$ times a year. I.e., $m = 26$. Then the amount earned after $7.343$ years is $A(7.343) = (1.035)\cdot\frac{((1.035)^7-1)\cdot 24000}{0.035} + \frac{1}{26}(1.035)^8 \cdot 24000 \cdot \lfloor 26 \cdot 0.343 \rfloor \approx 202965.$ I checked the case $N=7$ and it is consistent with the sum of the "Salary" column in your [link](http://www.easysurf.cc/samt8n3.htm?ansal=24000&ipcsal=3.5&time=7.373).

I am not sure whether or not this is what you're after, but I hope it gives some insight as to how you can come up with formulas in situations like these. If you need to make some minor adjustments to the formula, such as having the salary just after the first year being $x$ instead of $(p+1)x$, you can use a similar argument as above, just change $A(1)$ and go from there.